# Using SPListEventReceiver on Extended Web Applications

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have one site using windows form authentication used to admin (backend). This site have an Web Extension Site that uses FBA and is the site accessible to the common users (frontend).

In order to accomplish some implementation I've created and attached an custom SPListEventReceiver to one particular list from the principal website.

So, when I make changes into items, the custom handler is thrown and the singleton listening the event update the singleton element with the updated information from the SharePoint list updated. The problem: there is no notification to the extended site, so the singleton residing into extended site context is not  notified about the SharePoint list changes.

How I have to register the SPListEventReceiver in order to receive item changes notification on the extended site?

the class code

```
    public class CampagnasListItemEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            // DoSomething

        }
}
```

An the Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers >
      <Receiver>
        <Name>CampagnasListEventReceiverListAdded</Name>
        <Type>ListAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>{Class Namespace}</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I'm using the Singleton Pattern to manage an List into C# singleton class that is poblated with SharePoint list information, so when update the SharePoint list I need to update that c# list, it is working on principal site (backend) but the front end is not receiving the notification.

Comment: Why should there be an event notification fired in another web application? You didn't do the change from the second web app, but from the first one.

Comment: Have you used Extended Web Applications? This method to allows create a base site and share the content with the extended web application having, for example, two methods for autenticate: WindowsAut and FormBased. So, when I modify one item in the base site I want to make the same action in the extended site using the Event Receiver.

Comment: I'm using the Singleton Pattern to manage an List<T>, so when update the SPList I need to update that list. The problem is that there is two Singleton objects, one by web application.

Comment: Hi , could you please expand on this _so when update the SPList I need to update that list_ , Which list do u refer by _"that list"_ here ,is it another SharePoint List ? Also What do you mean by _you dont recieve the notification in the extended site_ . What kind of notification are you expecting , or you are suggesting that the event reciever doesnt get triggered for the extended site , when changes are done in Principal Site.

Comment: @Godwin I've updated the question. And yes, the receiver doesn't get triggered for the extended site when changes are done in Principal Site.

Comment: @rolivares - Thanks for the info ,  please understand that since the content is shared in extended web application, the event receiver need not(does not) be triggered in different contexts for a single change . The event receiver recognizes the context in which changes are being done and executes it , as its a shared content (essentially single content) , the event receiver will work only once as it does for any site. Basically you have to modify your code to handle this situation.

Comment: Cont...  Just the fact that what you refer to as backend(principal site) is getting populated means the event reciever is working fine , you can in the same code accordingly do the changes to update the front end.

Answer (score 0):

@rolivares - My understanding of your problem is that you have an in-memory list that you want updated when someone adds an item on your admin site. You've implemented this using a singleton object. But, the list is not updating on your extended site (frontend) when the event receiver fires on the admin site.

Although the 2 "sites" are pointing at the same content databases, IIS is running them as separate applications and therefore you will have 2 distinct instances of your singleton in-memory list. That is why your frontend is not being updated.

Comment: Yes, that is part of the context, but not the solution. I understand that I have two contexts, one by site (front and back). If SharePoint creates two sites using the same content database, I would expect that notifications where throw on both sites, but not.

So I think, because I do not have more arguments that the experience on the problem, that is a gap/bug from SharePoint but I need to find the official documentation or affirmation about my hypothesis  (or the solution to accomplish my goal).

Answer (score -1):

Accordingly to the element scheme you have missed the **ListUrl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/MyList"> <!-- ====== Modify accordingly ===== -->
      <Receiver>
        <Name>CampagnasListEventReceiverListAdded</Name>
        <Type>ListAdded</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>{Class Namespace}</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx) from MSDN

and this link for [MSDN Event Registration Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460929(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Please read the entire problem context, the problem is the notification in the extended site, not the principal site